# Form submission after dynamically adding new fields

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have a form for eg.

**HTML**

```
<form id="data">

  <input id="hostname" type="text" name="hostname" value="" />

</form>
```

And i have some javascript that adds more fields to the no. of friends i have.

Note: i will avoid adding some of the fb api scripts to save my writing time. add a comment if you want me to re-edit and add it.

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
<script>
//load fb api
//authenticate with permissions {scope: email,friends_birthday,users_birthday}

FB.api('/me/friends?fields=id,name,birthday',function (friendsdata) {

   for (var i = 0; i < friendsdata.data.length; i++) {


      $('#hostname').after('<input type="text" name="hostid[]" value="'+friendsdata.data[i].id+'" />');

    }

    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "php/send.php",
      data: $("#data").serializeArray(),
      success: function(send) {

      console.log(send);

      }
    });

  })      




</script>
```

**PHP**

```
$hostid = $_GET['hostid'];
print_r($hostid); // returns nothing if input field is generated using jquery after
```

The above works perfectly fine. it retrieves the data and inserts in into the fields.
But the problem is when i'm trying to post this data to a php file via ajax using serialize array.

I cannot receive ids array in php due to dynamic generation of the input fields.

if i simply add the id field manually it works fine.

Any Suggestions or solutions ?

**EDITS**

Ajax save method as requested by Arun.

Regards,
Dalton.

Comment: show your ajax save method

Comment: @ArunPJohny Hi Arun, I've updated the question with the ajax save method

Comment: Pls add the code, where you are making this ajax request.

Comment: I don't think it makes a difference but try adding the index to your input so `name="hostid[]"` becomes `name="hostid[' + i + ']"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of -

```
data: $("#data").serializeArray(),
```

Use this-

```
data: { hostid: $("#data").serializeArray()},
```

Comment: Hey this worked for me. But now i'm getting a new error and it says request url too large:jquery

Comment: stackoverflow.com/questions/8542061/… could help you for that. PS. dont forget to accept the answer if helped. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using

```
data: $("#data").serializeArray()
```

You can get the data like

```
// which will return a array.
var result  = $("input[name=hostid]").val();

// you can then serialize that array and pass to php

data:result.serializeArray()enter code here
```